# Prove that if $\lvert x-x_0\rvert$ <$ (\frac{\epsilon}{2})$ , $\lvert y-y_0\rvert$ < $(\frac{\epsilon}{2})$ then

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

...then

$\lvert (x+y)-(x_0+y_0)\rvert<\epsilon$

$\lvert (x-y)-(x_0-y_0)\rvert<\epsilon$

is an easy one, i guess that the only thing i need to do is to play with the inequalty in the first part, but in the second one I guess that I need to add something (I mean a 0) but I dont see how

Comment: Just so you know, if you put a `<` in your post, it hides *everything that follows it on that line*. So, your post looked like you were trying to prove the expressions: $$|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|\\|(x-y)-(x_0-y_0)|$$

Answer (score 2):

easily use triangle inequality $\lvert (x+y)-(x_0+y_0)\rvert <\vert x-x_0\vert +\vert y-y_0 \vert \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+ \frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$

for second

$\lvert (x-y)-(x_0-y_0)\rvert=\lvert (x-x_0)+(y_0 -y)\rvert  <\vert x-x_0\vert +\vert y_0 -y \vert \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+ \frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$

Comment: yea, that is an easy one, but I have some troubles with the second one.

Comment: I wrote it, too

Answer (score 1):

The second one can also be followed from the triangle inequality:
\begin{align}
|(x-y)-(x_0-y_0)|&=|x-x_0+(-y+y_0)|\\
&\le|x-x_0|+|-(1)(y-y_0)|\\
&=|x-x_0|+|(y-y_0)|\\
&<\varepsilon
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you have already proved the first part,

$$\lvert x-x_0\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \ \ \text{and} \ \ 
  \lvert y-y_0\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \implies
 \lvert (x+y)-(x_0+y_0)\rvert<\epsilon.$$

Now consider $\lvert (x-y)-(x_0-y_0)\rvert<\epsilon$.
This is equal to $\lvert (x+(-y))-(x_0+(-y_0))\rvert$.
But if
$\lvert y-y_0\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$
then
$\lvert (-y) - (-y_0)\rvert = \lvert -(y - y_0)\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$
too, and you can apply the fact you have already proved
(but using $-y$ and $-y_0$ in place of $y$ and $y_0$)
to conclude that 
$$\lvert x-x_0\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \ \ \text{and} \ \ 
  \lvert (-y) - (-y_0)\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \implies
 \lvert (x+(-y))-(x_0+(-y_0))\rvert<\epsilon.$$